# How to link typing-like nested classes and other urls with Sphinx and RST

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Using `intersphinx` and `autodoc`, having:

```
:param stores: Array of objects
:type stores: list[dict[str,int]]
```

Would result in an entry like:

- **stores** *([list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)[[dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)[[str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str),[int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int)]])* - Array of objects.

Is there a way to convert `list[dict[str,int]]` outside of the autodoc `:param:` derivative (or others like `:rtype:`) with raw RST (within the docstring) or programatically given a `'list[dict[str,int]]'` string?

Additionally, is it possible to use external links within the aforementioned example?

## Example

Consider a `script.py` file:

```py
def some_func(arg1):
  """
  This is a head description.

  :param arg1: The type of this param is hyperlinked.
  :type arg1: list[dict[str,int]]

  Is it possible to hyperlink this, here: dict[str,list[int]]

  Or even add custom references amongst the classes: dict[int,ref]

  Where *ref* links to a foreign, external source.
  """
```

Now in the Sphinx `conf.py` file add:

```py
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx'
]

intersphinx_mapping = {
  'py': ('https://docs.python.org/3', None),
}
```

In your `index.rst`, add:

```
Title
=====

.. toctree::
  :maxdepth: 2

.. autofunction:: script.some_func
```

And now simply `make` the html for the page.

The `list[dict[str,int]]` next to `:type arg1:` will be hyperlinked as shown at the beginning of this question, but `dict[str,list[int]]` obviously won't. Is there a way to make the latter behave like the former?

Comment: What are "typing-like nested classes"? What does "outside of the autodoc `:param:` derivative" mean? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: "typing-like" referred to the `typing` module with which you can do things like `List[Dict[str,int]]` (where `str` is nested in `Dict` which is nested in `List`. Outside of `:param:` means without using it, or `:type:` or `:rtype:` or any other derivative that automatically handles external referencing of classes. An example would be a one-line docstring with just `list[dict[str,int]]`.

Comment: I added an example with steps to reproduce, hope this helps clarify!

Comment: To create a link to a simple type like `dict`, you can use ``:obj:`dict` ``. I don't think there is an easy way to turn all components of `list[dict[str,int]]` into hyperlinks.

Comment: My issue with this approach is that it creates a link in <code>, rather simply using literal emphasis like the hyperlinks I showed.

Answer (score 0):

I reached a solution after digging around sphinx's code.

## Injecting External References (:param:)

I created a custom extension that connects to the `missing-reference` event and attempts to resolve unknown references.

Code of **reflinks.py**:

```py
import docutils.nodes as nodes

_cache = {}

def fill_cache(app):
    _cache.update(app.config.reflinks)

def missing_reference(app, env, node, contnode):
    target = node['reftarget']
    try:
        uri = _cache[target]
    except KeyError:
        return
    newnode = nodes.reference('', '', internal = False, refuri = uri)
    if not node.get('refexplicit'):
        name = target.replace('_', ' ') # style
        contnode = contnode.__class__(name, name)
    newnode.append(contnode)
    return newnode

def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value('reflinks', None, False)
    app.connect('builder-inited', fill_cache)
    app.connect('missing-reference', missing_reference, priority = 1000)
```

#### Explanation

I consulted [intersphinx](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3.x/sphinx/ext/intersphinx.py#L261)'s methodology for resolving unknown references and connected the function with high priority so it's hopefully only consulted as a last result.

#### Followup

Include the extenion.

Adding to **conf.py**:

```py
reflinks = {'google': 'https://google.com'}
```

Allowed for **script.py**:

```py
def some_func(arg1):
    """
    :param arg1: Google homepages.
    :type arg1: dict[str, google]
    """
```

Where `dict[str, google]` are now all hyperlinks.

## Formatting Nested Types

There were instances where I wanted to use type structures like `list[dict[str,myref]]` outside of fields like `:param:`, `:rtype:`, etc. Another short extension did the trick.

Code of **nestlinks.py**:

```py
import sphinx.domains.python as domain
import docutils.parsers.rst.roles as roles

_field = domain.PyTypedField('class')

def handle(name, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options = {}, content = []):
    refs = _field.make_xrefs('class', 'py', text)
    return (refs, [])

def setup(app):
    roles.register_local_role('nref', handle)
```

#### Explanation

After reading [this](https://docutils.readthedocs.io/en/sphinx-docs/howto/rst-roles.html) guide on roles, and digging [here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3.x/sphinx/util/docfields.py#L191) and [here](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3.x/sphinx/domains/python.py#L300) I realised that all I needed was a dummy field to handle the whole reference-making work and pretend like it's trying to reference classes.

#### Followup

Include the extension.

Now **script.py**:

```py
def some_func(arg1):
    """
    :param arg1: Google homepages.
    :type arg1: dict[str, google]

    Now this :nref:`list[dict[str,google]]` is hyperlinked!
    """
```

## Notes

- I am using [intersphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html) and [autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) to link to python's types and document my function's docstrings.
- I am not well-versed in Sphinx's underlying mechanisms so take my methodology with a grain of salt.
- The examples are provided are adjusted for the sake of being re-usable and generic and have **not** been tested.
- The usability of such features is obviously questionable and only necessary when libraries like [extlinks](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html) don't cover your needs.